# RequireJS callback not called in Typo3

Tags: javascript, php, typo3, requirejs, typo3-extensions

We are working on an Typo3 extension for a bigger university website and are struggling to get custom JavaScript code using RequireJS to run in the frontend. When we tried using RequireJS to load our dependencies, we couldnt get even a simple example to work.

We tried following the offical documentation https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/JavaScript/RequireJS/Index.html, but we just cant get `Test.say()` (see below) to be called.

Our project is structured as followed:

```
- Classes
  - (all our PHP code)
- Configuration
  - (AjaxRoutes, FlexForms and TCA) 
- Ressources
  - Private
    - Templates
      - Modulelist
        - List.html
  - Public
    - JavaScript
      - ListFilter.js
- composer.json
- ext_emconf.php
- ext_localconf.php
- ext_tables.sql
```

List.html:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers">
<!-- this is just some table filled by a controller -->
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td>Modulname</td>
        <td>OU Name</td>
        <td>ECTS</td>
    </tr>
    <f:for each="{modules}" as="module">
        <tr>
            <td align="top">{module.name}</td>
            <td align="top">
                <f:format.crop maxCharacters="100">{module.offeredBy.name}</f:format.crop>
            </td>
            <td align="top">{module.ects}</td>
        </tr>
    </f:for>
</table>

<!-- our extension is named DemoExtension -->
<f:be.pageRenderer
    includeRequireJsModules="{
        0:'TYPO3/CMS/DemoExtension/ListFilter'
    }"
/>
</html>
```

ListFilter.js:

```
console.log("ListFilter.js loaded");
define(['jquery', 'TYPO3/CMS/Core/DocumentService'], function($, DS) {
    console.log("List.html inside define");
    var Test = {
        message: "test"
    };

    Test.say = function() {
        alert(Test.message);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("List.html inside define, jQ callback");
        Test.say();
    });

    DS.ready().then(() => {
        console.log("List.html inside define, DS callback");
        Test.say();
    });

    return Test;
});
```

However, when loading the corresponding page, only the following line is printed to the console:

```
ListFilter.js loaded
```

We googled a lot but couldnt get it to work. What are we missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually load RequireJS?

The special RequireJS support in TYPO3 in the `PageRenderer` is only available for the backend.

Comment: This could be the problem. No we did not do that. How exactly do we load RequireJS for the frontend? Also, we may not request from other webservers than our own ones, so loading not loading it from our own typo3 server is not an option.

Comment: There are many possiblities. Here's a writeup https://pagemachine.de/blog/typo3-frontend-requirejs

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 does not load any Javascript by default in the frontend.

What your frontend renders is defined by your templates (typoscript/fluid)

You probably looking for page.includeJS or a similar configuration. But the best aproach can very widely depending on how you render your frontend and what other extensions you have in your site like vhs/flux

See this core document for reference of the PAGE OBJECT
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#page